# Reference for a folklore theorem about h-cobordisms

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology

I've seen referenced here that if $M$ and $N$ are closed topological $n$-manifolds and $f: \mathbb{R}\times M \to \mathbb{R}\times N$ is a homeomorphism, then $M$ and $N$ are h-cobordant.

I know that the first step of the proof is to consider the region between $f(0\times M)$ and $\varepsilon \times N$ in $\mathbb{R}\times N$. I see how this gives a cobordism from $M$ to $N$, but I fail to see how this region is an h-cobordism.

Comment: This can't be true. Let $M$ be a twice-punctured copy of $\mathbb R^2$, and let $N$ be a once-punctured torus.  Then $M \times \mathbb R$ and $N \times \mathbb R$ are homeomorphic -- they're both open genus 2 handlebodies.   I imagine you want some additional assumptions like compactness.

Comment: Ah! You're totally right, let's assume that the manifolds are closed.

Comment: See Igor Belegradek's comments to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/435116/21564) and the answer I wrote following them. Although the discussion there is in the smooth category, the arguments work exactly the same in the topological case.

Comment: Thank you! This is fantastic!